# Authenticating user in Symfony 6 app with Oktas self hosted Javascript widget

Tags: okta, symfony6

I have a Symfony 6 web app and I've integrated Okta's Javascript library. I am able to login to Okta through the widget but I'm not quite sure how to authenticate the user in the app with the response.

```
config.clientId = ClientID;
config.redirectUri = "https://localhost:8000/okta/verify";
config.authParams = {
    issuer: Issuer,
    pkce: false,
    responseType: "code",
    state: "state" || false,
    display: "page"
}

new OktaSignIn(config).renderEl(
    {
        el: '#widget-container',
        function(res) {

        }
    }
);
```

This loads the login screen which goes out and successfully authenticated with Okta. I have the route configured within Okta and my application to catch the response I'm just not sure what to do with it from there, create a custom authenticator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it's not quite clear what your requirements are. As a starter let me suggest that after you are authenticated, you can establish a session within your application (if you have a back-end). If you do not have a back-end, then you can obtain an access_token from Okta to use it in your calls to services.

I'm not familiar with Symphony so not sure if Okta has any library to support it seamlessly or native way. So you might have to rely on some basic principles of web-app/webAPI protection.

Comment: Thank you - I do have a back end. I noticed after a successful authentication with Okta in the response there is a code and a state value. I believe the next step is to get the access token you mentioned from Okta with these values but I'm not seeing anything in the documentation on how to go back to Okta and retrieve that access token.

Comment: you need to go to /token endpoint of your authorization server and present the code and proof of being a legitimate client (either PKCE verifier or client_id/client_secret). Read about OIDC authorization code flow